# float vs smallint vs decimal in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, decimal, tinyint

Now I have a table with impressions, clicks and ctr.

I was wondering if I should use tinyint(1) and store ctr which has a range from 1-250

or should I store it as a float which has more precision. or maybe decimal.

For statistics I would be calculating the ctr using clicks/impressions, so getting a precise value is not a problem.

But for performance what would be the best way to store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using php to calculate the CTR based on your mysql data, then there's no reason to use float or decimal - just use tinyint.

But if you want to have the CTR stored in the database, then use float - it's like a small version of decimal.

Comment: I am going to be using ctr quite often, do you think that precision is worth the performance.

Comment: Honestly, I can't imagine the volume you'd have to use to make much of a difference.  I would use the "correct" one (float) until/unless you actually notice a performance issue.  Even if your table is upwards of a few million records, I doubt you'll see any performance issues assuming your php is written well.

Comment: i have about 500 million records

Comment: btw i am getting a better insight from your answers, so giving you some rep mate.

Comment: wow - I guess now I can imagine a number that would make you worried about performance - 500 million! :)   thanks for the rep.  Even w/ 500 mil, imo I would still try float unless/until there's a noticeable performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about decimals, tinyint will be definitely more efficient than float.